# ArcGIS Server - Print Map aynschronously using Map_Only template

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online-basemaps

I'm trying to print a Map asynchronously using the ArcGIS printing tools. I'm successfully able to print the map using any template other than "MAP_ONLY". When i use "MAP_ONLY" template i get this error :
ERROR 001305: Missing or invalid 'exportOptions' property in WebMap; cannot derive a size for the output image. Failed to execute (Export Web Map). Failed to execute (Export Web Map Task). I'm not sure if there is a way to include the export options in the web map Json object. Here is the code:

```
 var initPrintParameters = function() {
        var temp = new PrintTemplate();
        temp.exportOptions = {
          width: dpi * 10, //3000, //960, //840,
          height: (20 * dpi) / 3, //640, //560,
          dpi: dpi
        };

        temp.format = "PNG32";
        temp.layout = "MAP_ONLY";
        temp.preserveScale = true;
        temp.showAttribution = true;

        printParameters = new PrintParameters();
        printParameters.format = "png32";
        printParameters.template = temp;
        printParameters.map = map;
        printParameters.outSpatialReference = map.spatialReference;
        printParameters.async=true;
    };

  var exportMapAtCurrentExtent = function() {
    printTask = PrintTask(printTaskUrl);
    initPrintParameters();
     var jsonMap = JSON.toJson(printTask._getPrintDefinition(map,printParameters));     
    var printLayout={  
      Web_Map_as_JSON: jsonMap,  
      Format: "PNG32",  
      Layout_Template: "A3 Landscape"
    };
      gp.submitJob(printLayout,gpJobComplete, gpJobStatus,gpJobFailed);
  };

  var gpJobComplete=function(jobInfo){
      console.log("Job Complete");
      console.log(jobInfo);
      gp.getResultData(jobInfo.jobId,"Output_File",getResultUrl);
  };

  var getResultUrl=function(result){
      console.log(result.value.url);
  };

  var gpJobStatus=function(jobInfo){
      console.log("Job Status");
      console.log(jobInfo);
  };

  var gpJobFailed=function(jobInfo){
      console.log("Job failed");
      console.log(jobInfo);
  };
```

In the above snippet the 'Layout_Template' is "A3_Landscape" and this works as i'm guessing the size of the map is predefined. I need to way to use the "Map_Only" template so that i can change the size of the map.

Answer (score 2):

I manually added the export options to the Web map json. Below is the code snippet.

```
 var exportMapAtCurrentExtent = function() {
    printTask = PrintTask(printTaskUrl);
    initPrintParameters();
     var jsonMap = JSON.toJson(printTask._getPrintDefinition(map,printParameters)); 
     jsonMap=jsonMap.replace(/\}$/, '');
     jsonMap=jsonMap+",'exportOptions':{'outputSize':[3000,2000],'dpi':300}}"   ;    
     var printLayout={  
       Web_Map_as_JSON: jsonMap,  
       Format: "PNG32",  
       Layout_Template: "MAP_ONLY"
     };
      gp.submitJob(printLayout,gpJobComplete, gpJobStatus,gpJobFailed);
  };
```